# Enhancement: misleading configuration for vmoption-files-screen of launcher configuration

Tags: install4j

We are using the new version 5.1.14. We want to set a directory path as a system property to use it in our application. This directory includes the `${installer:sys.installationDir}` variable at the *launcher->vm option file*-configuration screen like the following code:

```
-Xmx1024m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=128M 
-XX:PermSize=64M
-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
-Dreview.config.dir=${installer:sys.installationDir}${installer:sys.fileSeparator}${compiler:review.config.dir.name}
```

The installer variables were not replaced during installation. This vmoption-file will be generated during compile time, isn't it? So it is misleading for the developer to set an installer variable at this configuration screen for the launcher. The *Add VM Option* action instead works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Any unresolved installer variables will be replaced by the launcher in this case, so they are still functional.